# Is there a better way to unpack the Rest Body content

Tags: spring-boot

I do not have much experience with Spring-Boot framework,
I have received the following in the body of the Post Method
    FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Di&COMPANY=xyz+Software&EMAIL=xyz%40gmail.com&PHONE=08877564993

Obviously,they are name-value pairs, if there is a better way than just the string manipulation can you please provide the example or point me to the documentation.

Method signature looks as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/TEST", method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public User processIPN(@RequestBody String body) {..}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a Java Bean representing a request Body.

```
public class Person {
   // Define attributes as per request. Your request contains FIRST_NAME so you need to define.
    private String FIRST_NAME;

    // Define getters and setters

}
```

And then use below snippet to declare your REST API

```
@RequestMapping(value="/TEST", method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public User processIPN(@RequestBody Person person) {..}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sangram, after making the suggested changes I get the following error when the request received in controler

Comment: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method. I have some additional methods in it but that should not be the issue as all data will not be available always.

Comment: You may need to add MediaType in @RequestMapping annotation. How the request is made. Is it a javascript app doing form submit? . You can use consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE or MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE for Form submission

Comment: It is an enterprise web application, I guess it is using javascript. currently I am testing so sending the request using postman to send the request as text/plain. I will try MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE

Comment: MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE worked for me